# Is a Windows DNS cache entry invalided on IP connection failure?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ip, cache

We are changing a server's IP address. Say the DNS entry is updated for this server to point to that new IP address, but the client computer has cached the DNS entry with TTL 3600 (1hr). Say the browser (or other TCP/IP connection) uses the cached (now old) IP address and it fails to connect. An consultant suggests that this would cause the computer to invalidate that IP address's DNS cache entry on the client PC and query DNS for the new IP address. Is this true?

If it matters, this is a Windows AD/domain environment.

PS I do know clients can run "ipconfig /flushdns", or we can lower TTL in DNS to help resolve this potential issue, but that is not the question.

Comment: Theoretically, I think the DNS cache from client side will affect the connection to the server. The DNS caches save all information that’s relevant for name resolution, each with an entry known as TTL (time to live) where data remains valid for a given time. Within this time, corresponding queries are answered directly from the cache without requiring a detour to the DNS server. For more details about DNS cache, please refer to the following article: https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/flush-dns/

Comment: I have done a test in my lab, a hostname point to a new IP address, when I insert ping hostname in a CMD prompt, the host name cannot be ping successfully since the client initiated the connection with the old IP. But if I insert nslookup hostname, it can return the hostname with the new IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. DNS is purely the resolution of a domain name. Whether the service at the other end responds with a 200 code, a 4xx, or a 5xx is of no consequence.

DNS Gotchas:
TTLs & DNS Changes - Lower the TTL to 300(seconds) PRIOR to changing a DNS entry.
This allows client caches to be updated within a reasonable change window. Note that this has to be done far enough ahead of the change to allow the prior cached DNS entry to expire. For example, a TTL of 86400 has to be lowered to 300 at minimum 24 hours before the change.

DNS Diagnostics Tip: Get really familiar with Dig. On the command line (linux or mac), you can use 'dig +noall +answer website.com', to see what your DNS server is returning to you. You can query specific DNS servers by adding their hostname or IP to the end, like: 'dig +noall +answer 8.8.8.8'.

Comment: Thanks Alex... the question really is if the TCP/IP connection fails entirely (no HTTP code)... I could see where the TCP/IP stack could be smart enough to tell DNS to toss the cached entry, but I think this is highly unlikely... I think the answer is still "no". Do you agree?

Comment: No, connection outcome has no impact on your DNS cache. That would be an undesirable design. For example, if a popular site like ebay.com flops for a moment, you'd then incur a huge load against the global DNS infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks Alex... That makes sense, and I was able to confirm today... as I suspected, DNS entries are not tossed on an TCP/IP connection failure. Much appreciated!